# Can the Product of a Row-Stochastic and Non-Column-Stochastic Matrix and Another Stochastic Matrix Be Doubly Stochastic?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

I'm exploring the interaction between different types of stochastic matrices and came across a scenario that I find quite intriguing. Consider a nonnegative $(n \times n) $ matrix ($A$) that is row-stochastic (each row sums to 1) but not column-stochastic (at least one column does not sum to 1). My question is about the possibility of constructing a product matrix ($AB$) that is doubly stochastic, where ($B$) is any nonnegative stochastic matrix of the same dimension.

From an intuitive standpoint, it seems unlikely that the lack of column-stochastic property in ($A$) can be compensated for by any choice of ($B$), allowing ($AB$) to fulfill the criteria for being doubly stochastic. However, I'm uncertain if there might exist specific conditions or examples where this intuition does not hold.

Is there a formal proof or counterexample that can confirm or deny the possibility of ($AB$) being doubly stochastic under the given conditions?

Comment: Pick any $n\times n$ row stochastic matrix $A$. Let $B$ be $\frac{1}{n}$ times the matrix of ones. Then $AB=B$ is doubly stochastic.